# Volume using cylindrical coordinates

Tags: volume, cylindrical-coordinates

I have to find the volume of the solid which base is bounded by
$$x^{2}+y^{2}+2y=0$$
and it's bounded, above, by the surface
$$z=4-x^{2}-y^{2}$$

I tried to use cylindrical coordinates, where
$$x=r\cos\theta$$
$$y=r\sin\theta$$
and 
$$0\leq r\leq-2\sin\theta$$
$$\frac{\pi}{2}\leq\theta\leq\frac{3\pi}{2}$$

My points are: can $r$ be negative? Is the volume given by the double integral
$$\int_{\pi/2}^{3\pi/2}\int_{0}^{-2\sin\theta}(4-r^{2})rdrd\theta?$$

Comment: 1. No, the radius cannot be negative. 2. The integral gives the volume of another solid, not that described in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
Take shifted cylindrical coordinates where $$\begin{cases}x=r\cos t\\ y=-1+r\sin t\\ z=z\end{cases}$$ with $t \in [0,2\pi].$